# On bounty questions and downvotes

Tags: support, bounties, down-votes

If a bounty question's top answer has 3 upvotes and two downvotes, does that count as having two upvotes for the purpose of being automatically selected?

On [a question of mine on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/61072/is-there-any-equivalent-to-wine-for-running-mac-applications), there wasn't any such thing as what I was looking for. There were two answers posted, one linking to a dead site and the other giving a solution of how to do a similar thing, but as far as the question goes, it doesn't answer it. That answer has had at least +3/-2 (and possibly +4/-3). Since it is wrong, I don't want it marked as accepted, and am wondering if it will get automatically selected.

Comment: I *guess* it means "net", but...

Comment: FWIW: The answer in question was removed.

Comment: IMO the bounty is broken for cases like yours - where there are very few answers.  I have the same problem and have complained quite a bit about it, but Jeff and company don't seem to care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other places where a number of votes is quoted it is net - e.g. Peer Pressure badge or even the "Nice Answer" badge. To get these your post has to be at -3 or 10 which can be made any way (0/-3 or 1/-4 etc. and 10/0 or 20/-10 etc.).